# PHP callback in browser window

Tags: php, browser, callback, console, window

I'm trying to learn about PHP callbacks. I'm using examples from [phpriot.com](http://www.phpriot.com/articles/php-callbacks).

```
---------------this code-----------------------------
 // this function simulates downloading data from a site
    function downloadFromSites($sites, $callback = null)
    {
        $ret = array();

        foreach ($sites as $site) {
            sleep(2);

            $data = 'downloaded data here';

            // check if the callback is valid
            if (is_callable($callback)) {
                // callback is valid - call it with given arguments
                call_user_func($callback, $site, $data);
            }

            // write the data for this site to return array
            $ret[] = array(
                'site' => $site,
                'data' => $data
            );
        }

        return $ret;
    }

    // define a fictional class used for the callback
    class MyClass
    {
        // this is the callback method
        public static function downloadComplete($site, $data)
        {
            echo sprintf("Finished downloading from %s\n", $site);
        }
    }

    // imaginary list of sites to download from
    $sites = array(
        'http://www.example1.com',
        'http://www.example2.com'
        // more sites...
    );

    // start downloading and store the return data
    downloadFromSites($sites, array('MyClass', 'downloadComplete'));

    // we don't need to loop over the return data
    // now since the callback handles that instead
```

When you run this code, you will see that the "finished downloading" message is displayed as each site is completed rather than all at the end.

---

So, when I run this code in console it works fine: every 2 seconds a new line appears, but in the browser window I have to wait until the code finishes execution, only then do I see the results.

So the question is, Why does it work in the console, and not in the browser window?

Comment: You probably need to `flush()`, as console is interactive, however while executed in browser, script flushes output after script finishes.

Comment: I know, but where exactly should i put this flush?

Answer (score 2):

This is likely because of output buffering.

Output buffering is a mechanism in PHP that holds the output in memory until a later call to `flush` the buffer (also happens automatically when the script shuts down).

Output buffering allows you to print content inside of your script, and provide changes to HTTP headers after content has been printed. Normally, once you print content and send it to apache (who, in turn, sends it back to the client), you can no longer modify the HTTP headers. With output buffering, PHP will store this output in memory and won't hand it over to apache until you tell it to.

You should be able to get this to work in one of four ways:

- `ob_end_clean` at the very top of your PHP script to disable output buffering
- Disable `output_buffering` in php.ini
- Enable `implicit_flush` in php.ini (not recommended since it makes `output_buffering` pointless
- Call `ob_flush` after your `print`/`echo` statements

*Note:* There are also other very legitimate uses for output buffering, such as templating - but that's not important here.

**With that being said**

This won't necessarily work for everyone. Some browsers  by default, and others by configuration, won't start loading a page until the connection is closed and all HTML content has been received. If you want this to work across most every browser today - you might be better off making AJAX calls back to your server.

**Edit:** To tell if `output_buffering` is on, a simple call to `print ob_get_level()` will tell you. If that prints a number > 0, `output_buffering` is the culprit.

Comment: Hi, thanks to your answer. But i try all your solutions and nothing work. This is my browser Google Chrome 20.0.1132.11 Dev.

Comment: You put `ob_flush` after every call to `print`/`echo` and nothing worked? Can you please post what happens when you add `var_dump(ob_get_level()); exit;` right before your foreach loop?

Comment: i put ob_flush(); after this line of code echo sprintf("Finished downloading from %s\n", $site); and it doesn't work. var_dump(ob_get_level()); exit; this output int(1)

Comment: Yes, i put ob_end_clean(); before foreach, and i put ob_flush(); into static function downloadComplete($site, $data), after the echo. But result the same, it's wait 6 seconds then displays all 3 lines

Answer (score 0):

All scripts ran in console come up in real time. This is why it works in the console and not in browser. You have a few options-flush often enough(not a really good solution as most browsers won't be happy about this), use ob_start and on from there or use ajax which is your safest bet I think.